# Updating a LaunchTemplate and making it the default version with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm creating and updating a LaunchTemplate using AWS CDK, like

```
new ec2.LaunchTemplate(stack, "my-template", {
  launchTemplateName: "my-template",
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType("g3.4xlarge"),
  machineImage: ec2.MachineImage.lookup({ 
    name: "my-ami-*", 
    owners: [ACCOUNT_ID] 
  }),
  keyName: "my-key",
  role: myRole,
  securityGroup: mySecGroup
})
```

This creates a launch template as expected, but when I make changes, it results to a new version of the same template and the old version stays as the default. The intention is to update template default version so that when I launch instances using AWS SDK I get up to date instances.

So, how do I do this using AWS CDK?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't my only problem. Also it seems that when using the wildcard name selector as above, a new template version isnt' created when a matching AMI is created. I'd of course like to use the latest AMI matching the filter...

Comment: I found out that the RunInstances command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) allows setting launch template version. As an undocumented feature, you can use version number $Latest to use the latest template.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a solution, but a workaround.
You don't need to update default version in the Launch template, you can simply specify in the Autoscaling group to use the latest template version.

From AWS docs:
For Launch template version, choose whether the Auto Scaling group uses the default, the latest, or a specific version of the launch template when scaling out.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-asg-launch-template.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using Auto Scaling Groups, but a more custom way of launching and terminating instances using RunInstances command.

Comment: To add further, please note that you cannot modify the existing LaunchTemplate, whenever you modify any property in the launch template it will create a new version, now here the objective should be to find a parameter which sets the new version as default.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.LaunchTemplate.html

From what I understand, you can modify the "defaultVersionNumber" property to 'latest' as it excepts the string value.

Comment: No, you cannot modify defaultVersionNumber in the CDK LaunchTemplate object, that's a read-only property.

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of this AWS SDK API call to set the default version to the new version of the launch template using AWS CDK custom-resources package.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-launch-template.html

Comment: Yes, that can be done, but you cannot use this API to make "latest" the default. So, each time you update the LaunchTemplate using CDK, you'll have to make SDK calls to 1) find the newest version and 2) set that one as default. Pretty far from convenient.

Comment: I think if you integrate these SDK calls as a custom resources into your CDK stacks it will be easy because it will be updated automatically one you do CDK deploy for your launch templates. Custom resource example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html#custom-resources-for-aws-apis